# When there is a zero somewhere in the current time, converting it to binary fails

Tags: python, binary, clock

My task is to create a Binary Clock that converts the current time into binary. in the end, it should look like this:
(when time = 19:58:37)

```
hour    minute    second
0 1      0 1        0 0
0 0      1 0        0 1
0 0      0 0        1 1
1 1      1 0        1 1
```

My code looks like this:

```
from datetime import datetime

hour = 'datetime.now().hour'
minute = 'datetime.now().minute'
second = 'datetime.now().second'

hourc = str(hour)
minutec = str(minute)
secondc = str(second)

# cut
hour1 = hourc[:1]
hour2 = hourc[1:2]
minute1 = minutec[:1]
minute2 = minutec[1:2]
second1 = secondc[:1]
second2 = secondc[1:2]

# covert to binary
binstunde1 = '{0:04b}'.format(hour1)
binstunde2 = '{0:04b}'.format(int(hour2))

binminute1 = '{0:04b}'.format(int(minute1))
binminute2 = '{0:04b}'.format(int(minute2))

binsekunde1 = '{0:04b}'.format(int(second1))
binsekunde2 = '{0:04b}'.format(int(second2))
```

My problem at the moment is when there is a zero somewhere in the current time, I get an error message.
for example:
when the current time is 07:52:19 then I get the following error message:

```
binstunde1 = '{0:04b}'.format(int(hour1)) 
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'd'
```

I tried avoiding using integers and using strings instead but then I get this error message:

```
 binstunde1 = '{0:04b}'.format(hour1)
 ValueError: Unknown format code 'b' for object of type 'str'
```

My second problem would be that I can't figure out how to print the output vertically and next to each other like in my example.

Comment: That is not how you convert int to bianry? use `bin(integer)`

Comment: I tried to avoid that bcs it would need an extra part to cut this down to four digits bcs I couldnt figure how to make this command to only output four digits but when there is no way around then I will try this

Comment: Also it still creates the problem that it doesnt work when the current time contains a zero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to correct your code for:

**UPDATE According to your comments:**

```
from datetime import datetime

hour = str(datetime.now().hour)
if len(hour)==1:
    hour="0"+hour
minute = str(datetime.now().minute)
if len(minute)==1:
    minute="0"+minute
second = str(datetime.now().second)
if len(second)==1:
    second="0"+second


# cut
hour1 = hour[:1]
hour2 = hour[1:2]
minute1 = minute[:1]
minute2 = minute[1:2]
second1 = second[:1]
second2 = second[1:2]

# covert to binary
binstunde1 = '{0:04b}'.format(int(hour1))
binstunde2 = '{0:04b}'.format(int(hour2))

binminute1 = '{0:04b}'.format(int(minute1))
binminute2 = '{0:04b}'.format(int(minute2))

binsekunde1 = '{0:04b}'.format(int(second1))
binsekunde2 = '{0:04b}'.format(int(second2))

print('hour'+'\t'+'minute'+'\t'+'second')
print(binstunde1+'\t'+binminute1+'\t'+binsekunde1)
print(binstunde2+'\t'+binminute2+'\t'+binsekunde2)
```

result:

```
hour    minute  second
0000    0100    0101
1000    0100    0011
```

**Initial answer:**

```
from datetime import datetime
from itertools import zip_longest


hour = datetime.now().hour
minute = datetime.now().minute
second = datetime.now().second

print(hour,minute,second)

# covert to binary
binstunde1 = '{0:08b}'.format(hour)
binminute = '{0:08b}'.format(int(minute))
binsekunde = '{0:08b}'.format(int(second))

print('hour    '+'\t'+'minute  '+'\t'+'second')
print(binstunde1+'\t'+binminute+'\t'+binsekunde)
```

result:

```
hour            minute          second
00001000        00001101        00000011
```

Comment: I really need the all digits separately with only four digits and when I use this then I cant cut the number. I get this error message when I try to make "hour1 = hour[:1]" to only get the first digit of hour:  " hour1 = hour[:1]
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable"